# How to select elements from a table comprised in another table?

Tags: sql, subquery, inner-join

There is a table with an `id` and a code that represents the land-use type.
I have to select all elements whose land-use code is comprised also in another table (valid).

For example, code is a number from `1` to `100`, and the second table (valid) contains `20` random numbers

I tried to use a simple where function, but it didn't work out.

```
select id, code
from landuse
where landuse.code=valid.code
```

DO you have a suggestion? Thanks :)

**UPDATE: data samples**

valid:

[image: valid]

landuse:

[image: landuse]

The outcome has to be a column of codes like 4, 4, 4, 92, 92...

Comment: (1) Please provide sample data and desired results.  (2) Tag only with the database you are using.  I removed the inconsistent database tags.  (3) This sounds like a simple `JOIN`.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

If I follow you corectly, you could use `exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
select id, code 
from landuse l
where exists (select 1 from valid v where v.code = l.code)
```

If there are no duplicates in `valid`, an alternative is a `join`:

```
select l.id, l.code 
from landuse l
inner join valid v on v.code = l.code
```